# How to derive variable for each value in a column present

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Hi below is my dataset.

I need to calculate volume based on each shape. how do i apply the formula and not use too many for loops. I have more than 8-9 such unique values for which i need to calculate volume in the new derived variable

below is tha dataframe

Input :

```
  Type                   Len   wid    hig    dia
  cylinder                            165    42
  oval                   30    38     141 
  round                               131    48
  oval                   63    95     141
  cylinder                            120    42
```

Output:

```
  type                   Len   wid    hig    dia    vol
  cylinder                            165    42     238
  oval                   30    38     141           632
  round                               131    48     57
  oval                   63    95     141           200
  cylinder                            120    42     173
```

Code:

```
  def label_race (row):
     if Anomaly_1['Type'] == 'Cylindrical' :
        return (4/3*3.14*(Length/2)*(Width/2)*(Height/2))/1000
     if Anomaly_1['Type'] == 'Oval' :
        return (pi*(Diameter/2)^2*h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = Anomaly_1['Type'] == 'cylindrical'
m2 = Anomaly_1['Type'] == 'oval'
m3 = ... 

v1 = (4/3*3.14*(Anomaly_1['Len']/2)*(Anomaly_1['wid']/2)*(Anomaly_1['hig']/2))/1000
v2 = (np.pi*(Anomaly_1['dia']/2)**2*Anomaly_1['hig'])
v3 = ... 


Anomaly_1['vol'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [v1, v2, v3])
```

Another solution with custom function for processing values separately:

```
def f(x):
    if x['Type'] == 'cylindrical':
        return (4/3*3.14*(x['Len']/2)*(x['wid']/2)*(x['hig']/2))/1000
    elif x['Type'] == 'oval':
        return (np.pi*(x['dia']/2)**2*x['hig'])


Anomaly_1['vol'] = Anomaly_1.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single operation with the `pd.Dataframe.apply()` method. It can create a new column called, "Vol" that is the result of a function.

In this case your function might be something like:

```
def volume(shape: str = '', len: int = 1 , wid: int = 1, hig: int = 1 dia: int = 1) -> int:
    if shape == 'cylinder':
        vol = formula 
    elif shape == 'oval':
        vol = other formula
    elif shape == 'cylinder':
        vol = other other formula
    return vol
```